# Set child gameObject to be parent of another gameObject by defining parent's name in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do I set child gameObject to be a parent of another gameObject by defining name of the parent gameObject publicly?

```
public GameObject parent;
public GameObject child;
public string ParentsName; // to be defined

void Start()
{
   child.transform.SetParent(parent.gameObject.transform); //How to set parent.gameObject.transform as public string?
}
```

Comment: can you give an example?  If I read correctly you should just be able to say `ParentsName = parent.gameObject.name;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `GameObject.Find(string name)`

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html

It finds a GameObject in the hierarchy with the name matching the string parameter you give it.

Comment: If the object exists, and there is no guarantee that the object has been created yet since his code is in start.  Also the more GameObjects he has the more expensive this call is.

Comment: @Eddge why should the object not exist in `Start`? and in `Start` expensive calls are kind of allowed since it will be fired during the app loads so for a user there will be no notable lag

Comment: @derHugo Start is called on the frame a script is enabled (Before Update).  Creating and loading objects for a scene still happens while frames are running. As such some objects are still being created and instantiated when other objects are calling their start methods.  Try this in a large scene and you will run into issues where trying to find an object by name fails.  Also running an expensive command in start slows down your scene transitions.

Comment: @derHugo this is especially true in an environment where objects get created after scene initialization as well.

Comment: @Eddge sure .. but in all other cases and mostly used setups with a single scene and objects that already ate in the scene (otherwise OP wouldn't ask about how to get it's reference by name) it doesn't matter..

Comment: @derHugo anyways, I am more then willing to take this conversation into a chat, as this isn't the place for this conversation.